# Is there any point to using a kubernetes deployment when not using replicas?

Tags: kubernetes

My application has one pod per user, which is created/destroyed programmatically. I have no need to automatically replicate individual pods, as each pod has a different config depending on user settings. I know deployments are the recommended way to create pods, but I don't see any advantages other replication features. Is there any reason why I shouldn't just create standalone pods if I don't need pod replication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any reason why I shouldn't just create static pods if I don't need pod replication?

Sure, one can create unmanaged(?) Pods for all kinds of reasons, and if you don't need them restarted or scaled then that's a good reason

Be aware that the phrase "static Pod" generally means ones that are managed by `kubelet` directly, usually via putting the .yaml or .json in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` (or the value you have configured as [`staticPodPath:`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubelet/config/v1beta1#KubeletConfiguration)), and don't go through the `kube-scheduler` process. I don't have an authoritative source for the name one gives to a Pod created via the normal `kubectl create` flow, so I chose "unmanaged" since for the most part kubernetes will schedule it according to the usual constraints, and then leave it alone to fend for itself

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. I guess auto-restarting is still a worthwhile feature even if I'm not using replication.